# How can I view my pending edits?

Tags: support, help-center

After editing some questions I got `edit` saying that too many pending edits. So, I need to check them which of those are still in pending. This will also help me to revise them and keep track of my edited post.

How can see my pending edited posts ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at your activity on your user profile, there is a tab for "All Actions". Within that is a sub-tab which contains [all suggested edits you've made](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/131341/vivek-ji?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), and the list will show them as "pending" when they have not yet been reviewed:

[image]